# Getting all posts that by one user in Node express

Tags: reactjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have 2 models User & Posts and i need to write fuction that get all posts from selected user in route (/profile/:login) for profile page, where u  can find all posts by current user. I will be grateful for any help
User Model:

````
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    login: {
        type:String,
        requeired: true,
        unique:true
    }, 
    email: {
        type:String,
        requeired: true,
        unique:true
    }, 
    passwordHash:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
    },

    avatarURL:String,
}, 

{
    timestamps:true,
}
)
export default mongoose.model("User", userSchema);```

Post model;
```import mongoose  from "mongoose";
const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type:String,
        requeired: true,
        unique:true
    }, 
    text: {
        type:String,
        requeired: true,
        unique:true
    }, 
    viewsCount:{
        type:Number,
        default:0
    },
    imageURL:String,
    user: {
        type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:"User",
        required: true,
    }, 

}, 
{
    timestamps:true,
}
)
export default mongoose.model("Post", postSchema);```
````

Comment: i have only getAll and that looks like this if it can be useful


PostController:
```export const getAll = async (req, res) =>{
        const posts = await PostModel.find().populate("user").exec()
        res.json(posts)
}```
index.js:
```app.post("/posts", checkAuth ,PostCreateValidation, PostController.create)```

im tried to rewrite getAll function but i doesnt have a skill for this yet

Answer (score 0):

Here is a really simple query that will get you all `Post` documents based on the `userid` value in the route path:

```js
app.get('/profile/posts/:userid', async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const posts = await Post.find({user: req.params.userid});
        console.log('posts==', posts);
        res.status(200).json({
           posts : posts
        });
    } catch(err) {
       console.log(err)
       res.status(200).json({
          message : 'No post found'
       });
    }
});
```

Or if you are using sessions it would be:

```js
app.get('/profile/posts', async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const posts = await Post.find({user: req.session.userid});
        console.log('posts==', posts);
        res.status(200).json({
           posts : posts
        });
    } catch(err) {
       console.log(err)
       res.status(200).json({
          message : 'No post found'
       });
    }
});
```

**Edit**: just saw your comment.

Based on your current `getAll` function you could modify it to create a `getPostsByUser` function like so:

```js
export const getPostsByUser = async (req, res) =>{
    const posts = await Post.find({user: req.params.userid}).populate("user");
    res.status(200).json({
        posts : posts
    }); 
}
```

Then your route would be something like:

```js
app.get("/profile/:userid/posts", checkAuth, ControllerName.getPostsByUser)
```